# Using the Exited event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

Ok, I'm making a very basic vb.net winforms app, essentially you can drag files into it, and it then uses a batch file to process the files.

It's pretty simple and everything is going to plan so far, it accepts the right files, it uses the batch file to process them and the batch file does what it is supposed to.

The only problem is that I don't know how to hook into the `Exited` event that can/should be raised by the batch file process when the process completes...

I want the DOS window of the batch file to remain hidden while it is running, so I have used `ProcessStartInfo` to specify the batch file, then set the `WindowStyle` property of the process to `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimised`, then used `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myBatch)` to start the process at the appropriate moment.

This is fine, it works and does what I want. However, the only way to tell when a process ends is to use the `Exited` event. But the `Exited` event apparently only works with a `Process` not a `ProcessStartInfo`. I could switch to use `Process` instead but then I couldn't (AFAIK) run the DOS window minimised...

Is there a way around this? I've only been writing .net for a few days. This is how I'm running the batch file:

```
Dim myBatch As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\\batchFiles\\test.bat")

myBatch.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
system.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myBatch)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a process object and setting the StartInfo property.  You can then call WaitForExit instead of waiting for the event.  EG:

```
using(var process = new Process
                                  {
                                      StartInfo =
                                          new ProcessStartInfo("Foo.exe")
                                          {WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized}
                                  })
            {
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks :D

I used the following code in the end to get it to do what I want:

Dim proc As New Process
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\mybat.bat"
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
proc.Close()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the syntax in VB but I am almost sure that what you have to do is actually use the WIN API inline with managed code, and then you can use the MainWindowHandle of the Process Object.

```
[DllImport("User32")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```

The commands it takes, I would recommend reference to the win api library for this method.  But what you want to do I would think is very feasible with the interop.

Andrew

Comment: I don't know enough to translate this to VB, but thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx): This event can occur only if the value of the `EnableRaisingEvents` property is **true**.

So the following should work:

```
Dim procStart As New ProcessStartInfo
Dim WithEvents proc As New Process

Private Sub Button21_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button21.Click
        procStart.FileName = "C:\PTL\Bin\xxxxxx.exe"
        proc.StartInfo = procStart
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        proc.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub proc_Exited(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles proc.Exited
    Debug.WriteLine("Process Ended " + proc.ExitCode.ToString + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString)
End Sub
```